# Prevent merge if the custom labels are not present in Github

Tags: git, github, coding-style, standards, hygiene

I am setting up a hygiene development process for my team. As part of that, I want every code built to be unit tested and QA verified. I have created custom labels like QA Ready, Prod Ready for code repositories.
How do I ensure that a PR is not merged to master unless the above custom labels are present?

Comment: There is no "custom labels" in git, it is only in Github

Comment: Thanks. Corrected!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is : [**GitHub Actions**](https://github.com/features/actions)

> **Run a workflow on any GitHub event**
>
> Kick off workflows with GitHub events like push, issue creation, or a
>   new release. Combine and configure actions for the services you use,
>   built and maintained by the community.
>
> Whether you want to build a container, deploy a web service, or
>   automate welcoming new users to your open source projects—there's an
>   action for that. Pair GitHub Packages with Actions to simplify package
>   management, including version updates, fast distribution with our
>   global CDN, and dependency resolution, using your existing
>   GITHUB_TOKEN.

You can explore existing GitHub Actions in the [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions).

A quick search on the marketplace and I found this GitHub Action [**Enforce PR label**](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/enforce-pr-label).